# Fetch nested results as JSON PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, json

Consider the following tables

```
Device
--------
id
name
type
--------

components
--------
id INT
type VARCHAR
--------

Manufacturers
-------------
id INT
name VARCHAR
country VARCHAR
-------------

Device_components
-----------------
deviceid REFERENCES Devices(id)
componentid REFERENCES Components(id)
-----------------

Component_Manufacturers
-----------------------
componentid REFERENCES Components(id)
manufacturerid REFERENCES Manufacturers(id)
-----------------------
```

I want to query the database to return something like this:

```
{
 "id": 1,
  "name": "phone",
  "components": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "screen",
      "manufacturers": [
       {
         "id": 1,
          "name": "a",
          "country": "Germany"
        }
      ]
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
      "type": "keyboard",
      "manufacturers": [
        {
         "id": 1,
          "name": "a",
          "country": "UK"
        }
     ]
   }
  ]
}
```

So far I'm selecting from each table individually and then assemble the JSON object in my application.

Here's some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Devices
(
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Components
(
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Manufacturers
(
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    COUNTRY VARCHAR(40)
);  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Device_components
(
DeviceID INT REFERENCES Devices(ID),
ComponentID INT REFERENCES Components(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Component_manufacturers
(
ComponentID INT REFERENCES Components(ID),
ManufacturerID INT REFERENCES Manufacturers(ID)
);

INSERT INTO Devices (NAME) VALUES ('phone');
INSERT INTO Devices (NAME) VALUES ('tablet');
INSERT INTO Devices (NAME) VALUES ('pc');

INSERT INTO Components (NAME) VALUES ('mouse');
INSERT INTO Components (NAME) VALUES ('camera');
INSERT INTO Components (NAME) VALUES ('screen');

INSERT INTO Manufacturers (NAME,Country) VALUES ('foo','france');
INSERT INTO Manufacturers (NAME,Country) VALUES ('bar','spain');
INSERT INTO Manufacturers (NAME,Country) VALUES ('baz','germany');

INSERT INTO Device_components VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO Device_components VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO Device_components VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO Device_components VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO Device_components VALUES (3,1);
INSERT INTO Device_components VALUES (3,2);
INSERT INTO Device_components VALUES (3,3);

INSERT INTO Component_manufacturers VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO Component_manufacturers VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO Component_manufacturers VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO Component_manufacturers VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO Component_manufacturers VALUES (3,3);
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data - http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? I don't really feel like dummying up the data, but without dummy data it's pretty darn hard to work on this.

Comment: @CraigRinger I had trouble executing the query at sqlfiddle, so I edited my question to include it.

Comment: Works for me - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8e991

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, so you seem to want to create a graph from a join tree. That's a pretty natural thing to want to do.

It's not as easy as it should be in Pg, mainly because of the lack of support for column-aliases in the `record` pseudo-type.

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT row_to_json(r, true)
FROM (
    SELECT
        d.id,   
        d.name, 
        json_agg(c_row) AS components
    FROM devices d
    INNER JOIN device_components dc ON (dc.deviceid = d.id)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  
            c.id,       
            c.name,     
            json_agg(m) AS manufacturers
        FROM components c
        INNER JOIN component_manufacturers cm ON (cm.componentid = c.id) 
        INNER JOIN manufacturers m ON (cm.manufacturerid = m.id) 
        GROUP BY c.id 
    ) c_row ON (c_row.id = dc.componentid)
    GROUP BY d.id
) r(id, name, component);
```

The general idea here is, at every level of object nesting where you're producing an array of objects, use `json_agg` in a `group_by`. The `json_agg` function implicitly calls `row_to_json` to transform a rowtype into json. In the `SELECT` clause specify aliases for the synthetic columns so the json key names are correct when the row is fed into the outer level.

As the outer level isn't aggregated, use `row_to_json` over a subquery instead of using `json_agg`. If you want a single json result instead of a set of json rows, you can change `row_to_json` to `json_agg` in the outer level.

I've only tested on 9.3, as that's what I have installed and sqlfiddle seems to be having some issues.

**Update**: [Unfortunately `json_agg` doesn't exist on 9.2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8e991/3), it was added in 9.3. However, this is a simple enough case that you can just use `array_agg` instead, so [this should work in 9.2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8e991/4):

```
SELECT row_to_json(r, true)
FROM (
    SELECT
        d.id,   
        d.name, 
        array_agg(c_row) AS components
    FROM devices d
    INNER JOIN device_components dc ON (dc.deviceid = d.id)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  
            c.id,       
            c.name,     
            array_agg(m) AS manufacturers
        FROM components c
        INNER JOIN component_manufacturers cm ON (cm.componentid = c.id) 
        INNER JOIN manufacturers m ON (cm.manufacturerid = m.id) 
        GROUP BY c.id 
    ) c_row ON (c_row.id = dc.componentid)
    GROUP BY d.id
) r(id, name, component);
```

Ideally PostgreSQL would support this sort of query more naturally, without the subqueries, but I think we'd need a new join type, or at least some functions to use with lateral queries. It [all plans out into a civilised query plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/YqN) anyway (though it'd be better with suitable indexes):

```
                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on r  (cost=1050.26..1282.94 rows=720 width=106)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1050.26..1273.94 rows=720 width=188)
         ->  Merge Join  (cost=1050.26..1226.42 rows=7704 width=188)
               Merge Cond: (d.id = dc.deviceid)
               ->  Index Scan using devices_pkey on devices d  (cost=0.15..58.95 rows=720 width=82)
               ->  Sort  (cost=1050.11..1069.37 rows=7704 width=110)
                     Sort Key: dc.deviceid
                     ->  Merge Join  (cost=403.16..552.77 rows=7704 width=110)
                           Merge Cond: (c_row.id = dc.componentid)
                           ->  Subquery Scan on c_row  (cost=253.38..285.63 rows=720 width=110)
                                 ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=253.38..278.43 rows=720 width=286)
                                       ->  Sort  (cost=253.38..258.73 rows=2140 width=286)
                                             Sort Key: c.id
                                             ->  Hash Join  (cost=44.75..135.00 rows=2140 width=286)
                                                   Hash Cond: (cm.manufacturerid = m.id)
                                                   ->  Hash Join  (cost=26.20..87.03 rows=2140 width=86)
                                                         Hash Cond: (cm.componentid = c.id)
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on component_manufacturers cm  (cost=0.00..31.40 rows=2140 width=8)
                                                         ->  Hash  (cost=17.20..17.20 rows=720 width=82)
                                                               ->  Seq Scan on components c  (cost=0.00..17.20 rows=720 width=82)
                                                   ->  Hash  (cost=13.80..13.80 rows=380 width=208)
                                                         ->  Seq Scan on manufacturers m  (cost=0.00..13.80 rows=380 width=208)
                           ->  Sort  (cost=149.78..155.13 rows=2140 width=8)
                                 Sort Key: dc.componentid
                                 ->  Seq Scan on device_components dc  (cost=0.00..31.40 rows=2140 width=8)
(25 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I was looking for. In theory you could go down n times right? Just being curious here, but, it would be interesting if it could be done backwards for updating and inserting, right?

Comment: Correct, you can descend pretty much to an unlimited level, though performance may stat to suck. Reversing for updating is a *hard* problem, because there could be deletions/additions as well as changes. You'd probably have to construct the current tree, walk them both in tandem to find differences, and then apply the changes iteratively.